# After initialising with factory, I can’t access the instances from the initialised class

Tags: python, kivy

I’ve initialised the MyFirebase module using factory and now I still can’t access the instances in the MyFirebase module from the ProfileWindow class. Anybody that can notify the issue in the code. I am trying to access the localId instance from the MyFirebase module. After several hours of trying to resolve the issue I can’t spot it.I would appreciate it if any one would be of any assistance

```
from kivy.app import App
import requests
import json

from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyFireBase(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.localId = None
        self.sign_up_request = None

    def sign_up(self, email, password):

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            self.sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(self.sign_up_request.ok)
            print(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())


            if self.sign_up_request.ok == True:
                print(sign_up_data)
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']

                # Save refreshToken to a file
                with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(refresh_token)

                app.local_id = self.localId
                app.id_token = idToken

                my_data =  '{"avatar": "profilepic.png", "jobs_done": "", "jobs_posted": ""}'
                post_request = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + self.localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken, data=my_data)
                print(post_request.ok)
                print(post_request.content.decode())

                app.root.current = "create"

            elif self.sign_up_request.ok == False:

                error_data = json.loads(self.sign_up_request.content.decode())
                error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
                app.root.ids.signup.ids.signup_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

    def send_user_details(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        my_data ={"first name": app.root.ids.create.ids.first_name.text, "last name": app.root.ids.create.ids.last_name.text,
                   "phone number": app.root.ids.create.ids.phone_number.text, "job1": app.root.ids.create.ids.job1.text, "job2": app.root.ids.create.ids.job2.text,
                   "job3": app.root.ids.create.ids.job3.text, "date of birth": app.root.ids.create.ids.date_of_birth.text, "state": app.root.ids.create.ids.state1.text}

        user_details = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + app.local_id + ".json?auth=" + app.id_token,  json.dumps(my_data))
        print(user_details.ok)
        print(user_details.content.decode())

        app.root.current = "main"

    def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
        signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
        signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(signin_request.ok)
        print(signin_request.content.decode())

        if signin_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
            # Save refreshToken to a file
            with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)

            app.root.current = "main"

        elif signin_request.ok == False:
            error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
            error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
            app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

#thefirebase = MyFireBase()    # not needed
Factory.register('MyFireBase', cls=MyFireBase)   # register MyFireBase so that it is available in kv

class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    thefirebase = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.thefirebase = kwargs.pop('firebase', None)   # use kwargs to pass the firebase to eliminate the required positional arg
        super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #self.thefirebase = thefirebase   # not needed

    def print(self):
        print(self.thefirebase.localId)


class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"

    def build(self):
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        return sm


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

#sm = WindowManager()    # not needed, sm is built by the `kv` file


# sm.current = "page"    # not needed, it is the default

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy.kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

WindowManager:
    id: window manager
    ProfileWindow:
        id: page
        name: "page"
        thefirebase: Factory.MyFireBase()   # this builds thefirebase
        Button:
            text: 'ProfileWindow'   # just so the ProfileWindow has something to display
            on_release: page.print()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: The `page.print()` in the `kv` file is accessing the `thefirebase` instance from the `ProfileWindow` `Screen`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you bro, but I’m trying a new method seems like I can’t figure this out can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860705/how-can-you-initialise-an-instance-in-a-kivy-screen-widget?noredirect=1#comment105860084_59860705