# How can you initialise an instance in a Kivy screen widget

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to access an instance variable named self.localId in my kivy screen and it keeps saying the saying the instance doesn't exist after i have initialised it. I know I have an error In my code but im having a hard time identifying it. is there a different way to initialising instances in a kivy screen? but here is my code. I would appreciate any help

mainfile.py

```
from kivy.app import App
import requests
import json
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from firebase import firebase



class LoginWindow(Screen):
   pass


class ProfileWindow(Screen):


   def __init__(self):
       self.localId = None






   def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
       signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
       signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
       signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
       sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
       app = App.get_running_app()
       print(signin_request.ok)
       print(signin_request.content.decode())

       if signin_request.ok == True:
           refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

           self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
           idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
           # Save refreshToken to a file
           with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
               f.write(refresh_token)

               print(sign_up_data['localId'])



           app.root.current = "page"

       elif signin_request.ok == False:
           error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
           error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
           app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")



   def print_localId(self):
       print(self.localId.text)


   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)




window = ProfileWindow()




class MyApp(App):
   refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"


   def build(self):
       self.page = ProfileWindow()
       self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file

       return sm


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
   pass


sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

#sm = WindowManager() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

kivy.kv

```
WindowManager:
   id: window manager
   LoginWindow:
       id: login
       name: "login"
   ProfileWindow:
       id: page
       name: "page"



<LoginWindow>

   canvas.before:
       Color:
           rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
       Rectangle:
           pos: self.pos
           size: self.size


   TextInput:
       id: email
       hint_text: "Email"
       multiline: False
       pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2 , "center_y":0.9}
       size_hint: 0.4, 0.10

   TextInput:
       id: password
       hint_text: "Password"
       multiline: False
       pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "center_y": 0.8}
       size_hint: 0.4, 0.10
       password: True


   Button:
       pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.05}
       size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
       text: "Login"
       font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2)  / 14**4
       background_color: (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0)
       background_normal: ''
       on_release:
           app.page.sign_in_existing_user(email.text, password.text)

<ProfileWindow>:


   canvas.before:
       Color:
           rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
       Rectangle:
           pos: self.pos
           size: self.size

   Button:
       pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.05}
       size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
       text: "Print localId"
       font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2)  / 14**4
       background_color: (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0)
       background_normal: ''
       on_release:
           root.print_localId()
```

Traceback

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/mainfile.py", line 109, in <module>
    MyApp().run()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
    runTouchApp()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
    EventLoop.window.mainloop()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
    self._mainloop()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
    EventLoop.idle()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
    self.dispatch_input()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
    post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
    wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
    self.dispatch('on_release')
  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
  File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
    exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/kivy.kv", line 86, in <module>
    root.print_localId()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test6/mainfile.py", line 73, in print_localId
    print(self.localId.text)
AttributeError: 'ProfileWindow' object has no attribute 'localId'
```

Comment: Why do you keep askling the same questions with different accounts and then removing the others?

Comment: @RandomUser The more recent the question, the more attention it gets

Comment: It's annoying for people who follow tags. And even so, give it some time, be a bit patient. This same question was only asked today as well. And deleting it is disrespectful to the people who answered and tried to help.

Comment: Please add the contend of your kv file because it is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Your traceback indicates an error in your `test5/kivy.kv` file, but you haven't provided that file. Impossible to tell what is wrong without seeing that file.

Comment: Your error message says that `ProfileWindow` has no `localId`, but your `ProfileWindow` code shows `self.localId = None`. These things do not make sense. Until you post a [mcve], I will no longer respond to your posted questions.

Comment: @JohnAnderson sorry bro, ive updated the code with a mre with the login details to be able to access it. ill appreciate if you take a look it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `__init__()` methods in `ProfileWindow`. The second redefines, overwriting the first, and does not create the `localId` attribute. Your one and only `__init__()` method in `ProfileWindow` should be:

```
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(ProfileWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self.localId = None
```

The next problem is that you are creating 3 instances of `ProfileWindow`. You only need one. So remove the line:

```
window = ProfileWindow()
```

and from your `build()` method in the `App`, remove:

```
self.page = ProfileWindow()
```

The `ProfileWindow` is created by the line in your code:

```
sm = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
```

any other use of `ProfileWindow()` creates a new instance of `ProfileWindow` that is not part of your GUI.

Next, you need to access the correct instance of `ProfileWindow` when you press the `Login` `Button`. To do that, make use of the `ids` in your `kv` file as:

```
    on_release:
        app.root.ids.page.sign_in_existing_user(email.text, password.text)
```

And, what I think is the final error, your `print_localId()` method tries to print the `text` attribute of `localId`, but it does not have such an attribute. Just change that method to:

```
   def print_localId(self):
       print(self.localId)
```

Comment: Love you bro, appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

When comparing with my code you miss the definition of localId in kivy.kv and you don't initiate the object as Property. 
So it would be:

Code:

```
class ProfileWindow(Screen):
    localId = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        self.localId = None
```

test5.kv

```
<ProfileWindow>:
    name: "page"
    localId: localId
```